# Alternatives to throw an exception to minimize performance hit

Tags: java, performance, exception

I’m trying to optimize a java application and there are `try`/`catch` blocks in which the `catch` throws an exception:

```
try { 
    //call a web service 
} catch (Exception subclass){
    throws someOtherExceptionSubclass();
}
```

Apparently this is a big performance hit so I thought of returning `null`. So where should the `null` be after the `catch` block?

```
try {
    // call a web service 
} catch (Exception subclass){
    //Print some exception related message 
}

if ( webService.call() == "unsuccessful" ) {
    return null;
} else {
    return "Success";
}
```

What is the right place to put `return null`? Is there any other housekeeping to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can just do this instead of multiple return statements

```
    boolean isSuccess = true;
    try {
        call a web service 
    } catch (exceptions subclass) {
        //Print some exception related message 
        isSuccess = false
    } 


   return isSuccess;
```